# Why doesn't computed column calculation show up in the the Execution Plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-execution-plan

I have a table with a computed column.  It is not persisted.

```
create table dbo.Cases (
  ...
  CaseName varchar(20) not null,
  NickName AS (dbo.fn_ParseCaseNickName(CaseName)),
  ...
)
```

When I execute a query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 c.NickName, * 
FROM dbo.Cases c (NOLOCK)
WHERE c.ID_Case = 294426
```

I get the following execution plan with nothing about fn_ParseCaseNickName function:

[image]

However, when I ask for an Estimated Execution Plan, SSMS does show the function execution:

[image]

Why am I not seeing `fn_ParseCaseNickName` function in the actual execution plan?

Comment: Wat do you think that `compute scalar` step is doing?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ahh, I see.  The tooltip says nothing about the function though.  https://i.imgur.com/l4txmcv.png

But I think you are right, because when I look at the execution plan XML, the function name is buried there.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why they didn't put it there, especially since the performance pitfalls of scalar-valued functions make it so important to know when one is being invoked. If you look at the XML of the plan, the function invocation is clearly there (`UserDefinedFunction`).

Comment: Quite simply SQL Server doesn't elaborate on some of the details in an execution plan, scalar functions are a well-known black-box that always get given a default cost estimate irrespective of what they are doing; 2019 improved on this with scalar-function inlining where the execution plan actually includes operators used in the function (when it works and if your function meets the every-increasing restrictions as they fix bugs) but it's still best to avoid functions if possible, or at least tune a query with the code manually inlined.

Comment: you should also be aware that making a computed column in the table reference a scalar UDF will block that table participating in parallel plans

Comment: ^And not just that table, but any objects that directly or indirectly reference that table in their dependency stack, such as views, or views on top of views on top of that table.

Comment: @MartinSmith What if I make the computed column `PERSISTED`?  Would that unblock it?